# Cassandra backup running on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, database-backups

I have a cluster of 3 Cassandra pods running on Kubernetes. I want to do automatic backup of my data and for that I need to run nodetool snaphot command inside of each container and I need to invoke it remotely. What is the correct way to do it from architectural point of view? 
Do I need modify cassandra image to have ssh deamon in it or do I need to have helper containers in cassandra pods or to do this by 'kubectl exec' Kubernetes API calls? Other options?

Comment: A sidecar type of pattern seems like one way to address this use-case for now. There is a snapshotting API in development (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44172) that you should be able to leverage in the future.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan thanks for your answer. I've also thought about sidecar pattern, but as for me there is to much overhead(java and python are requred to run nodetool) and it will be needed for every single cassandra container. No sure that k8s snapshotting API will help me because before doing snaphot I still have to say to cassandra to flush everything that it have in memory to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think k8s `cronJob` resource - is what you need for backing up the data via `nodetool`. Generally, the `cronJob` has `jobTemplate` section with `spec` section within. The `spec` section, in turn, has containers definition, almost the same as in the `Deployment`. You can build your own docker image with `nodetool` in it (or try to find somewhere on dockerhub) and run it with your own specific configuration.

More info:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/